# C++ regex not working in Android NDK

Tags: c++, regex, android-ndk

I have the following piece of code

```
#include <string>
struct Confs{
    std::string regexp;
};

class foo
{
public:
    static int search(const std::string& phrase);
    static const Confs configs[];
};



const Confs foo::configs[] = {
    //Regular Expresion
    {"^adb"}, //Example
    {"^qwr"}, //Example
    {"^a5eo"}, //Real
};

int foo::search(const std::string& phrase){
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(configs)/sizeof(Confs); i++){
        std::regex re(configs[i].regexp);
        if (std::regex_search(phrase, re)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << foo::search("a5eo_asd") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I search for "a5eo_asd" it does not find a match. Even removing the "^" at the begining. No match.

**Compiled with ndk-build (clang, NDK 10d), and gnustl_static c++11.**

However, the compilation with other toolschains make the same code to work (Android platform build, desktop g++). What is the ambiguous thing I am doing so that the code founds a match in a platform and not in another?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: NDK10d, using clang (I am not sure if clang 3.4 or 3.5), gnustl_static as C++ library, compiling for armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Ok, I am using plain string compares, but I would still value if someone can enlighten me what is the proper way of using regex in NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the open source free regex matcher ([here](https://github.com/DanielHsH/Regex-Matcher)).
Its tiny, cross platform, extremely fast, and does not have any dependencies.
Just copy the files into your source and you are ready to go

Comment: Thanks, this provides a fixed code that works everywhere. It is not a proper answer of "why" crashes for NDK, but I accept it because it solves the issue.

Comment: I know. I had those issues as well on many platforms (not only android). Many libraries, including built in C++11 <regex> and Android NDK, just have bugs. Plain and simple bugs (This code was written by mortals like us, that have mistakes). I had to write this library myself because I was fed up with crashes, out of memory exceptions, stack overflows and slow processing time. If the crash occurs on PC its easy to debug, but when it happens on a feature phone, or embedded devices it is a nightmare. Hope that explains the "WHY".

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ Library is not supported fully in Google's Android NDK, in particular things related to locales, wide characters and regular expressions. This is known fact for years, even though with time it become better; unfortunately, not so quickly as developers need. So your example don't work *exactly* because of poor support of C++ in Android NDK.

Solution: use [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk) or modify your code to fit limitations of Google's NDK.

P.S. I've just built your example with CrystaX NDK and it works as expected.

Comment: CrystaX NDK says they support C++11 thanks to clag. But so does google in the latests NDKs, since they added clang as the default compiler. And it indeed compiles, but does not work as expected. This seems like a bug, or ambiguous problem, rather than just lacking support. (I assume regex_search is not a no-op function)

Comment: This particular thing has nothing to clang, as well as to gcc. Regular expressions are implemented in C++ Standard Library, and in Google's Android NDK both GNU and LLVM implementations are not complete due to lack of support of many things from underlying layer - libc. So many things just don't work properly - locales, wide characters and regular expressions, in particular. Again, this is not because of compiler; this is just library issue.