# C++ regex matches on ideone.com but not in Android NDK build

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have the following program working correctly in [ideone](http://ideone.com/zhPczb)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    if (regex_match("test", regex("^[_a-z0-9]{3,12}$"))) {
        cout << "match" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "no match" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It matches as expected. Just checking for a string containing between 3 and 12 alphanumeric characters or underscores.

However, the same code run in native code on Android (built using ndk-build with gnustl_shared) fails (does not match).

If regexes aren't properly supported under Android, shouldn't my build fail to compile? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Maybe this helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390658/c-regex-not-working-in-android-ndk

Comment: @mxscho I did look at that question, but the accepted answer says "use a library". What's unclear to me is how this code can compile but not function correctly. Why would a compiler accept calls to `regex_match` if it can't correctly compute the result?

Comment: I read the thread and as I understood not the compiler itself is the problem but rather the NDK/library you're using which implements the C++11 standard (the standard only defines how these functions should look and what they should do, but how they're implemented is up to the library) is wrong (or contains bugs). Of course it can still be compiled and the compiler has nothing to do with this. However, I just wanted to point you there in case you didn't see it. Maybe there's another one who knows the exact reason why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue today, 
and in my own experience, just change the "_" position in the expression.

for my example, 
just replace

```
std::regex reg("[^. _A-Za-z0-9]");
```

with

```
std::regex reg("[^. A-Za-z0-9_]");
```

and it works fine, maybe it is because the gcc version is too old.